# How to parallelize a Jenkins job?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, mockito

I want to speed up the Jenkins job through parallelizing the test stages. The idea is to move each test stage to a separate node. What I've found is the `parallel` keyword. When I used this I ran into several problems:

- The timing seems to be different. I had to adapt several tests.
- Mocking seems to have issues in parallel mode.

For me it seems that the parallel stages are running on the same machine/node. Is there an opportunity to force the different stages to run on different nodes so that they don't influence each other?

One of the errors I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedMockingSessionException: 
Unfinished mocking session detected.
Previous MockitoSession was not concluded with 'finishMocking()'.
For examples of correct usage see javadoc for MockitoSession class.
```

The Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
  options {
    timeout(time: 120, unit: 'MINUTES')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '30' : '5'))
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  agent {
    label 'win10'
  }
  stages {
    stage('cleanWs and checkoutCode') {
      steps {
        cleanWs()
        script {
          checkoutCode()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        bat 'gradlew showJavaVersion'
        bat 'gradlew printVersion'
        bat 'gradlew compileKotlin compileTestKotlin compileJava compileTestJava compileIntTestJava --parallel'
        bat 'git status'
      }
    }
    stage('tests') {
      parallel {
        stage("unit tests without ui") {
          environment {
            // give each build testing its own random port
            BDP_HTTP_MOCK_PORT = 0
          }
          steps {
            bat 'gradlew test -x :ui:test -x :bdp-ui:test -x :bdp-mock:test -P headless=true -P maxParallelIntegrationTests=3 -P os=win --parallel'
          }
        }

        stage("mock tests") {
          environment {
            // give each build testing its own random port
            BDP_HTTP_MOCK_PORT = 0
          }
          steps {
            bat 'gradlew :bdp-mock:test -P headless=true -P maxParallelIntegrationTests=3 -P os=win --parallel'
          }
        }
        stage("unit tests with ui") {
          environment {
            // give each build testing its own random port
            BDP_HTTP_MOCK_PORT = 0
          }
          steps {
            bat 'gradlew :ui:test :bdp-ui:test -P headless=true -P maxParallelIntegrationTests=3 -P os=win --parallel'
          }
        }
      } // parallel
    } // stage('tests')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of fixing this:

1. Use only a single slot on the test machines:
   Pros: Very simple, foolproof way of avoiding interference between tests
   Cons: Using a single slot might be wasteful if the machine could actually handle more
2. use [locks](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/), make sure you have the NODE_NAME be part of the lock's name
   Pros: Fine-grained control over which parts of the pipeline need locking
   Cons: locks won't influence where the stage will be scheduled, just make processes wait who want the lock
3. Apply a different scheduling strategy, for example [Least Load](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/), or round robbin. This will distribute load better and make clashes less likely.
   Pros: Better load balancing
   Cons: Doesn't actually prevent clashes

In my opinion, I would say a combination of using locks, and changing the scheduler, is the right way to do this (unless someone comes up with a better way I don't know). Locks guarantee that no tests will interfere, and round-robbin scheduling / Least Load will make it less likely a process needs to wait for the lock to be released.

Comment: Thanks. But how can the different stages interfere each other when they are running on different nodes? One more step I don't understand when parallelizing is that the first 2 steps `checkout` and `build` are run only once on a single machine. How does Jenkins handle this when the tests are run on different machines?

Comment: @MartinBammer I don't think I understand these questions. Processes on different nodes shouldn't interfere with each other (but, if you use a lock, it will wait for that lock regardless of on what node the process is running, hence including the node name in the lock). Jenkins can stash the wrkspace or parts of it and unstash them for the test stage. What I did in one case was stash the built artifacts, and checkout in each test stage to get the test sources (repo wasn't big). https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build